# form submit action error emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a submit action on a register form. here is my register handlebar:

```
  <form class="form-signin" {{action "register" on="submit"}}>
    {{input class="form-control" value=username type="text" placeholder="Username"}}
    {{input class="form-control" value=password type="password" placeholder="Password" }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
```

here is the router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('register', {path: '/register'});
});

export default Router;
```

and here is my register controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    register: function(){
        return 'hello';
    }
});
```

when I submit the form I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'register'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the action property in the controller. It should look like this:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        register: function(){
            alert('hey');
        }
    }
});
```